# Any workarounds for using a RefEdit control inside a Frame control when designing a UserForm in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I tried to emulate the UserForm design in Data>DataAnalysis>Regression as below, but got very strange errors, usually Excel just crashes. After some googling, it seems the error is because I put RefEdit control inside the frame control. I then deleted the frames and everything went well.

[image]

But I have to say having frames makes the interface pretty clear, for instance, it hels separate my input and output options. I wonder how Excel skips this bug and if there is any workarounds in my case.

Comment: If you like these four lines (frames) so much then you can still put four images on the form consisting of four lines to enframe your controls. It seems that most bugs are eliminated as soon as RefEdits are being placed directly on the form (with no layer in between).

Comment: No, i mean that RefEdits should not be on top of (or inside) another control. So, you should not place a RefEdit on a picture (depicting a box) or inside a frame. Yet you should be able to place one picture to the top, to the left, to the right, and to the bottom (making it a frame / box) of a RefEdit without a problem: http://peltiertech.com/using-refedit-controls-in-excel-dialogs/